# слишком много вопросов в очереди на закрытие, за которые нет «стартового» голоса

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок

очень часто в [очереди проверок «за закрытие»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) встречаются вопросы, за закрытие которых (это видно в диалоге закрытия, открывающемся при нажатии на кнопку «закрыть») на момент моей проверки не отдано **ни одного** голоса.

сегодня я решил написать этот вопрос, потому сохранял ссылки на такие проверки:

1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/126398
2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/126484
3. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/126524

три из двадцати (даже из девятнадцати — вроде, была и тестовая «проверка бдительности») — непонятно каким образом попали в очередь проверки.

да, конечно, тот, кто нажал ссылку «закрыть» под вопросом, мог потом отозвать свой «голос».

но ведь не может быть, чтобы каждый день по нескольку голосов отзывали. я встречаю подобную ситуацию ежедневно, а ведь это только те случаи, в которых мне было ясно видно, что ни одного голоса не было.

может быть, вопросы в эту очередь попадают ещё каким-нибудь «обходным путём»?

Comment: скорее всего просто жали тревога. а не закрыть

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все эти проверки были инициированы тревогами от участников, имеющих менее 3000 (а именно 65, 600 и 825) баллов репутации. У них нет возможности отдать первый голос в проверке (не бывает действия «рекомендовать закрытие» аналогичного «рекомендовать удаление» в проверках VLQ).

Давайте посмотрим на проверки детально.

1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/126398. Тут действительно слишком много кода, не относящегося к проблеме. **Тревога верная.**
2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/126484. Не вполне очевидно, как там реализованы вкладки и каковы критерии адаптации под мобильную версию. Возможно, для эксперта по фронтенду ответ на оба вопроса однозначен и ясен, поэтому я воздержусь от голосования. **Тревога похожа на верную**, и использование её вполне оправдано. В зависимости от знаний инициатора это может быть «вопрос совершенно точно неполный» или «вопрос похож на неполный, но я не уверен, проверьте пожалуйста».
3. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/126524. Тревога сразу была за закрытие вопроса как дубликата, инициатор указал другой вопрос, практически идентичный данному. Снова **тревога верная.**

Похоже, участники без привилегии закрытия вопросов используют тревоги достаточно корректно. Напомню, что по результатам проверки такая тревога подтверждается или отклоняется. Если какой-либо участник будет злоупотреблять тревогами или часто ошибаться, появится много спорных тревог и система ограничит возможность их использовать.

Comment: То есть они могут внести вопрос в очередь проверок, но голоса за закрытие при этом не добавляется?

Comment: @alexolut ага, именно это и происходит.

Comment: странно, что эта же возможность сохраняется при достижении нужного для голосования за закрытие уровня репутации.

Comment: @alexolut  Если вы оставите тревогу за закрытие, разве не засчитается голос за закрытие?

Comment: Засчитывается. Вероятно, бес попутал :)

Comment: Может для таких вопросов в очереди актуально уменьшить порог для исключения из оной?

Comment: @alexolut какую проблему/задачу мы решим таким образом?

Comment: очередь будет уменьшаться быстрее.

Comment: `<режим-зануды>` а какую проблему или задачу это решит в свою очередь? В данном случае тревоги были более-менее верные, но всё-таки не от участников с 3000 репутации. Могут быть и ошибочные. Почему должно быть нужно меньше участников, чтобы подтвердить или отклонить такие тревоги?

Comment: репутация дает привилегии, т.к. увеличивает доверие к участнику. Логично предположить, что отсутствие репутации - меньше доверия, а стало быть на этом тоже можно строить дополнительную логику. Для подтверждения тревог - меньше быть не должно. Но вот для отклонения - вполне.